# How to select some bits from byte?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to get some bits from a byte, like this:

251 dec = 11111011 bin

I want to get bit 3 until bit 6.

I created a function:

```
function ExtractBitsRL (value, bits_start, bits_len: Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result := ((value shr (bits_start - 1)) and ((1 shl bits_len) - 1));
end;
```

Usage:

```
b := ExtractBitsRL (251,3,3);
```

And the result is: 110  is OK.

But

```
b := ExtractBitsRL (176,1,4);
```

176 dec = 10110000 bin

the result is: 0000 not 1011

I cannot find my mistake. (I'm using Delphi 7)

Comment: And how to get bit 1 to 4?

Comment: I want to get bit from the middle. I believe that you give a light, because my function is getting Right to Left and not Left to Right.

Comment: You have bits 0-3. You want bits 4-7, so presumably ExtractBitsRL(176, 5, 4 ). Your code says (10110000 shr (1-1)) and (00010000 -1) = (10110000 shr 0) and (00001111) = 10110000 and 00001111 = 0.

Comment: @kobik, bits are usually enumerated from 0.

Comment: @kobik, the OP probably is counting from 1. (And from left to right, hmm)

Comment: @WellingtonTellesCunha, Like I said in my (deleted) comment: your function is correct by getting the bits from right to left. I would only *consider*  zero-based index for `bits_start`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  definitely use unusual one-based numeration, so look at this table:

```
bit number  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
176 dec =   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
251 dec =   1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
```

and your function gives right result.

But seems you imagine reverse bit order. LSB is the rightmost bit in binary record.  So to extract `1011` from `176 dec`, you need arguments `5,4`

Note that in your (reversed) interpretation result should look as `1101` instead of `1011`

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use common rules. Note that your interpretation reverse bit order, and with Dsm approach you'll get `1101` instead of `1011`

Answer (score 0):

To use the mode of counting that you want use

```
function ExtractBitsRL (value, bits_start, bits_len: Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result := ((value shr (9 - bits_start - bits_len )) and ((1 shl bits_len) - 1));
  // would be 8 if you started at bit zero
end;
```